# Rethinkdb getAll , orderBy with index - Tags

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm new to rethinkdb and i love it, but i found some problems when i tried to optimize my query and make it work on bigger datasets.
The problem is simple.

I need to filter my "event" table by timestamp (row.to) , by tag (row.tags), order by timestamp (row.from) and then slice for pagination.

row.tags has a multi index and works well!

row.from and row.to are start/end time of Event.

The slow query (testeded on 100k entries) is this:

```
r.db("test").table("event")
.getAll(r.args(["148a6e03-b6c3-4092-afa0-3b6d1a4555cd","7008d4b0-d859-49f3-b9e0-2e121f000ddf"]), {"index": "tags"})
.filter(function(row) {return row("to").ge(r.epochTime(1480460400));})
.orderBy(r.asc("from"))
.slice(0,20)
```

I created an index on 'from' and tried to do

```
.orderBy(r.asc("from"),{index:'from'})
```

but i get

> e: Indexed order_by can only be performed on a TABLE or TABLE_SLICE in:

I already read about problems about index intersection in Rethinkdb, but maybe i miss something, maybe there is a way of doing this simple task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason RethinkDB complains is this:
`getAll` returns a `selection`. When `filter` is applied to a `selection` it returns a `selection`. When `orderBy` is applied to a `selection` the `index` parameter can't be used (it can only be used when `orderBy` is applied to a `table`).

`orderBy` can be applied to a `table`, `sequence` or `selection`. *Only* when it's applied to `table` can the `index` parameter be used. This makes sense as the index is updated when rows are added and removed from the table.

In your case, you are applying `orderBy` on a result of `filter` which is a `selection`. In order to sort a selection the database needs to:

1. read all elements into memory (by default max is 100,000 elements)
2. sort them using the provided function or field

and it can't use index in this case.

The way to improve your query might be to sort the table first and then apply the filter. You will be able to use the index in this case.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I already did it, but if i sort with index, than i cannot use getAll anymore!